# TextBox Value gets blank on Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a application in MVC2 by choosing (ASP.Net MVC 2 Web Application). This provided some Home/About Controllers/Models/Views.

### I additionally created a Model with the Name of Index like below...

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Index
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Following is my Index View

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) 
        {%>
    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Name) %>
    <input type="submit" name="Click here" />
    <%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

### Following is my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Index Model)
{
      ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
      return View();
}
```

### Question

When I keep the Index controller like below. and If I click the submit button. This is clearing the TextBox COntrols. Like below

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
          ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
          return View();
    }
```

TextBox will not be cleared in case in incorporating the Model as Parameter in the Action method...

What's the reason for this behaviour ?

Comment: Not getting the question... What are you trying to do? what's  not working?

Comment: @gdoron - As you know we have ViewState in ASP.Net to preserve the data in TextBox after PostBack. right? But MVC is stateless. I am looking to preserve the data in textbox in MVC. Actually I new to MVC. Can you please explain how is MVC preserving the data in textbox after PostBack after including the Model Parameter ?

Comment: [`ModelState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate(v=vs.108).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

MVC doesn't maintain state between postbacks like WebForms does.

Fields are repopulated from values in the ModelState which are only added there if they are seen by the modelbinder on postback (and potentially only if there is a validation error?). Honestly i would almost prefer if it didn't do it automatically. However if you postback an invalid value (eg a string to an integer field) you need an somewhere which can store the invalid value so it can be repopulated along with a validation error.

Other than that automatic method, you need to manually pass the model back to the view for it to be populated

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Index Model)
{
  ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
  return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: So can I just type `[Required]` for the Property in Model ? andcan I keep it going repopulated automatically ?

Comment: No, the action actually has to accept a model with the property on it.

Comment: Could not understand it...Kindly explain.

Comment: @testing The key to this ( if I properly understand what it is you are asking ) is the code you posted : return View(); passes nothing to the view, thus resulting in your 'blank' textbox.  While Betty's code : return View( model ); does pass data to the view, allowing for the model binding invoked by your TextboxFor to work.

Comment: Betty and @Forty-Two I am getting the TextBox repopulated only after adding the Model State parameter in the Action method. without passing it to the `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should look like this for the user input to persit in the view after the submit button is clicked '

```
public ActionResult Index( )
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    var model = new Index();
    return View( model );
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Index model )
{

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: No, Try with removing the model from View Parameter and make it like this `return View();` It will work.

Comment: Also why `[HttpPost]` should be included in the action...? Because I am submitting the form? Form submitting is good even without this line of code. Isn't it? or I am missing something?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: can you give a very short answer that why should i use `HttpPost`. As submitting is happening without it. Thanks for the article. I will go through it definitely...

Comment: HttpPost specifies that that overload of the Index method can be invoked only for POST requests.

Comment: ok. Are you agree with this point **with removing the model from View Parameter and make it like this return View(); It will work.**? I mean it will repoulate the fields